# Could note save image on local disk using Nodejs on Elastic Beanstalk AWS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, multer

I have a problem with my web application deploying on Elastic Beanstalk AWS. The problem is when I test program locally, it perfectly save image into local disk by Multer library. Then I uploaded ZIP code file to Elastic Beanstalk and uploaded images, then I re-download source code then see that there is no any image is saved. I dont know why?
Anyone have any suggestion please tell me.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you checked any EB logs? Also if you ssh into the EB instance, can you insect if the files are locaed there, but maybe in different folder then expected?

Comment: Hello @Marcin, Tks for your comment. I also checked the EB logs and there is no error display, then I downloaded  the source code(ZIP file on elastic beanstalk) to check, no image on the folder I want. I think that the problem may be by the source link to save image inside a ZIP file when I uploaded into ELB AWS.????

Comment: "downloaded the source code" what do you mean by that?

Comment: Store image into local disk ( eg, folder /image) inside ZIP source code webapp which I uploaded in to Elastic Beanstalk on AWS. So, after submit image to store in /image folder inside ZIP, I downloaded whole ZIP source code and go to /image folder to check whether images saved or not. But I dont see any image. Moreover, to make sure that the save image is normal, I also create a route to store on S3 too. In S3, I can see the image saved. But it is not in /image folder local inside ELB

Comment: ZIP source code will not contain your images. Its just the original zip file which you uploaded. You have to ssh into the EB instance, and check there.

Comment: Okay, Thank you @Marcin